# Find a node rank using gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I have nodes in Neo4j with multiple relationships , like follows, country, region etc. But I want to calculate pagerank/node rank for only nodes with relationship Follows . Is there any tutorial to do this using Gremlin .

```
17838 - Follows->1743
17838 - Country-> 2
....
```

ps: Please share any good tutorial for Gremlin

So I came up with this :

```
gremlin> m = [:].withDefault{1}
gremlin>g.V.transform{rank=m[it.name];neighbors = it.out('Follows').toList();degree = neighbors.size();neighbors.each{m[it.name]=m[it.name]+(rank/degree);}neighbors;}.scatter.range(0,10000).loop(3){true}.iterate()
```

This gives me null pointer exception ???

Comment: I don't have the exact answer, but maybe this blog inspires you: http://markorodriguez.com/ (by one of the main contributors of Gremlin)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as such.

```
g.V.out('follows').groupCount(m).loop(2){it.loops < 5}
```

Good Gremlin tutorials are here:

```
http://gremlin.tinkerpop.com
http://gremlindocs.com
```

Comment: Marko , I read your blogs . Keep up the good work . I learned a lot from them.

Comment: I cant understand really understand above code , all I get after this command is number of vertices printed on my terminal. I think I need to drill down more into gremlin

Comment: m.sort{it.value}
I get output as v[17901] = 104434 , these are eigen vector values? and yet so high in values?

Comment: How to access key, value in m

Comment: But I want to assign weights as 1/degree I am confused to do this using loop

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using Cypher. A good starting point might be the following query:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[:FOLLOWS]-m
RETURN n,m
```

Comment: This can be done using gremlin : g.V.outE('Follows').outV.map

But this doesn't help in giving node ranks